# Spring IntegrationFlow Disallow Concurrent Execution

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way we could instruct Spring IntegrationFlow DSL to avoid concurrent execution, for example - first run is still not completed however as per the Poller it is time for the second run? Similar to @DisallowConcurrentExecution we use in Spring Batch Quartz scheduler.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid concurrent execution from the polling channel adapter, you really must not use anything that could lead for parallelism. First: don't use a `TaskExecutor` for the polling tasks. Second don't use `fixedRate` and just `fixedDelay`. The second one behaves the way that it does schedule the next polling task only when the previous has finished. And if you don't shift the work to other thread (see that `TaskExecutor`), anything is going to be performed on the same scheduled thread.

Technically what you are asking is there by default if you just use a `fixedDelay` for the poller and no more other options are configured.

Although you need to keep in mind that that the rest of your flow must be direct as well: no `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel` in use!

Also see docs for conditional polling if you still cannot make your flow direct and blocking: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers

Comment: Thx for the clear explanation. We use Fixed thread TaskExecutor and cannot run on a single thread. Hence, going to try limiting the max rows on the message source and change the fixed rate to fixed delay. On a worst case scenario, it would be just those number of (fixed thread) records that could get picked by the second run

Comment: On a related note, when exactly does the updateSql() on the Jdbc message source gets invoked that is used by an IntegrationFlow with TaskExecutor? Is it right after the message is picked by the Thread or when the Thread completes?

Comment: Just immediately after `SELECT`, so that is done in the same thread even before message is produced.